# JTable to read and write on a specific file

Tags: java, jtable

I'm programming in Java and I'm having a bit of problem with this project.

The project requires to read a dynamic Excel/csv file exported from a database, writing the data into a jtable, having the possibility to modify the data in the jtable and saving the changes back into the original file.

Atm I've managed to dynamically read the file and putting that into the jtable (I've read the file and extracted a string with all the data and then I divided it into a matrix), I can modify the jtable but I don't really know how to save the changes and applying them to the original file, my boss mentioned a bind to the file but I haven't found much.

Even a general direction would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

This is my code for now, I've decided to separate the code in different classes to make the code smoother to read, hope class is just main, index opens a button to trigger the filechooser, the filechooser is a filechooser, GUI class is the core of the code, based on the extension of the file, it calls different methods and puts the data into the jtable, READER classes parse the file and MATRIX transforms data (MEGA string with all the data) into a string MATRIX.

```
**//HOPE CLASS**

public class hope {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        index.index();
    }
}

**//INDEX CLASS**

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class index {  
    static void index(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FILE");
        JButton button=new JButton("SCEGLI FILE");
        
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        button.setBounds(150,150,200,200);
    
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                String filename = FileChooser.filename();
                String estensione = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf("."), filename.length());
                GUI.creation(filename, estensione);
                
            }
        });
    }
}  

**//FILE CHOOSER**

import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class FileChooser {
    
    static String filename(){
        
        JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
        
        FileFilter xlsx = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel File", "xlsx");
        FileFilter csv = new FileNameExtensionFilter("CSV File", "csv");
        FileFilter xml = new FileNameExtensionFilter("XML File", "xml");
        FileFilter json = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JSON file", "json");

        chooser.setFileFilter(xlsx);
        chooser.setFileFilter(csv);
        chooser.setFileFilter(xml);
        chooser.setFileFilter(json);
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String filename = file.getAbsolutePath(); 
        
        return filename;
    }
}

**//GUI CLASS**

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;  
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class GUI {
    
    static void creation(final String filename, final String estensione){
        

    String data= "";
    int r = 0;
    int c = 0;
                
    if(estensione.equals(".xlsx")){
        //parsing the file
        data = Excel.carica(filename);
        //getting row number
        r = Excel.riga(filename);
        //getting column number
        c = Excel.colonna(filename);
    }
                
    if(estensione.equals(".csv")){
        //parsing the file
        data = CSV.carica(filename);
        //getting row number
        r = CSV.riga(filename);
        //getting column number
        c = CSV.colonna(filename);
    }
                
    if(estensione.equals(".xml")){  
    }
                
    if(estensione.equals(".json")){
    }
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();  
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    //column names
    String[] colonne = Matrix.colonne(data, r, c);
    //data matrix
    String[][] datMat = Matrix.mat(data, r, c);
    
    JTable table = new JTable(datMat,colonne);
    table.createDefaultColumnsFromModel();
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));  
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

**//EXCEL READER**

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Excel {
     
    //file parse 
    static String carica(String filename){
    
         String data = "";
         
         try{
             File file = new File(filename);
             FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
             XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);   
             XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
             Iterator<Row> itr = sheet.iterator();
        
             while (itr.hasNext()){  
                 Row row = itr.next();  
                 Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            
                 while (cellIterator.hasNext()){
                
                     Cell cell = cellIterator.next(); 
                
                     switch (cell.getCellType()){  
                
                     case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        data += cell.getStringCellValue() + " "; 
                        break;
                    
                     case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        int y;
                        y= (int) cell.getNumericCellValue();
                        data += y + " ";
                        break; 
                    
                     default:  
                     }
                 }        
             }
             fis.close();
        
         }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Errore" + e);}
         return data;
     }
    
    //row number
    static int riga(String filename){
        int r=0;
        try{
            File file = new File(filename);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);   
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            r = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        }catch(Exception e){}
        return r;
    }
    
    //column number
    static int colonna(String filename){
        int c = 0;
        try{
            File file = new File(filename);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);   
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            c = sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Errore" + e);}
        return c;
    }
}

**//CSV READER**

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CSV {
    
    //file parse
    static String carica(String filename){
        
         String data = "";
         try {
             Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)));
             scanIn.useDelimiter(",");
             String [] InArray;
             String s;
                while(scanIn.hasNextLine()){
                    s = scanIn.nextLine();
                    InArray = s.split(",");
                    for(int i=0;i<InArray.length;i++){
                        data += InArray[i] + " ";
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }
         return data;
    }
    
    //row number
    static int riga(String filename){
        int r=0;
         try {
             Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)));
             scanIn.useDelimiter(",");
             String [] InArray;
             String s;
                while(scanIn.hasNextLine()){
                    s = scanIn.nextLine();
                    InArray = s.split(",");
                    r++;
                }
         }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Errore" + e);}
         return r;
    }
    
    //column number
    static int colonna(String filename){
        int c = 0;
        try {
            Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)));
            scanIn.useDelimiter("");
            String [] InArray;
            String s;
            while(scanIn.hasNextLine()){
                s = scanIn.nextLine();
                InArray = s.split(",");
                c = InArray.length;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Errore" + e);}
        return c;
    }
}

**//MATRIX CLASS**

public class Matrix {
    //matrix data
    static String[][] mat(String data, int r, int c){
        
        String[] datArray = null;
        datArray = data.split(" ");
        final String[][] datMat = new String[r-1][c];
        int x = c;
        
        for (int i = 1; i< r; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j< c; j++){
                datMat[i-1][j] = datArray[x];
                x++;
            }
        }
        
        return datMat;
    }
    
    //column names
    static String[] colonne(String data, int r, int c){
        
        String[] datArray = null;
        datArray = data.split(" ");
        final String colonna[] = new String[c];
        int x = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i< c; i++){
            colonna[i] = datArray[x];
            x++;
        }
        
        return colonna;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't apply the changes to the original file. You need to recreate the file will all the data in the table.

Comment: Creating an application model made up of one or more plain Java getter/setter classes helps to separate your concerns and allows you to focus on one part of the application at a time.  You then read the file into your model, use the model with your GUI, and write the file from the model.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) section.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.